# Formatting Date-time Returns 24-10-2018T00:00:00 when i try to format 10/24/2018 12:00:00 AM

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, formatting

I was trying to Parse 10/24/2018 12:00:00 AM date to 10-24-2018T12:15:25

I tried 
`datetimeobject.AfterDate.Date.ToString(@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss")`

It is returning me 12-10-2018T00:00:00

How can i get 12-10-2018T12:15:25

Comment: `I was trying to Parse 10/24/2018 12:00:00 AM date to 10-24-2018T12:15:25` Well, this is _not_ what "parsing" means. There are time difference between them. You can use `AddMinutes` and `AddSeconds` method with `datetimeobject.AfterDate.Date` and you can use `ToString` method after it.

Comment: @SonerGönül you can't add minutes to the Date component of a DateTime. He's selected the Date component, that's why tine is set to 00:00.

Comment: @Haldo Why? `.Date` property still returns `DateTime`. BTW sorry but this question does not too much sense. Day part is 24 on the first example but 12 in the second. I don't believe that code would return `12-10-2018T00:00:00` in any case since it should be print 4-digit year value first etc..

Comment: @SonerGönül It returns a DateTime where the time component is set to 00:00:00. Yes, the question does not make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

The wording of the question is difficult to understand, however, I'll make a best guess. I'm assuming `datetimeobject` is not actually a `DateTime` object but some other class which contains a DateTime `AfterDate`.

It looks like you are selecting the Date part of the DateTime object. Update your code to `datetimeobject.AfterDate.ToString(@"s", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`. Here were using the standard DateTime format specifier "s" which results in the format: "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss".

Comment: Note that without the single quotes around `:`, the culture-specific time separator would be used. I'd personally use the invariant culture instead though - otherwise the year/month/day parts may well use a non-Gregorian calendar unexpectedly.